# GooglePlayGamesManifest.plugin is missing AndroidManifest.xml file. [Unity]

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, build-error

I am trying to implement leaderboards into my game, but when building for Android I get this error:

```
Project 'E:\Unity\Project\Cave Boat\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\GooglePlayGamesManifest.plugin' is missing AndroidManifest.xml file.
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr, Boolean&)
```

The plugin I use is CloudOnce. There are no errors on runtime, only when building.

That error is one of 3, here are the other two;

2:

```
    UnityException: Adding Android library projects failed!
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidLibraries.AddLibraryProject (System.String projectPropertiesPath) (at <5f8140421e7d41ada100b629c3033aa7>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidLibraries.FindAndAddLibraryProjects (System.String searchPattern) (at <5f8140421e7d41ada100b629c3033aa7>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.AddAndroidLibraries.Execute (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context) (at <5f8140421e7d41ada100b629c3033aa7>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessRunner.RunAllTasks (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context) (at <5f8140421e7d41ada100b629c3033aa7>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessAndroidPlayer.PostProcess (UnityEditor.BuildTarget target, System.String stagingAreaData, System.String stagingArea, System.String playerPackage, System.String installPath, System.String companyName, System.String productName, UnityEditor.BuildOptions options, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry usedClassRegistry, UnityEditor.Build.Reporting.BuildReport report) (at <5f8140421e7d41ada100b629c3033aa7>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidBuildPostprocessor.PostProcess (UnityEditor.Modules.BuildPostProcessArgs args, UnityEditor.BuildProperties& outProperties) (at <5f8140421e7d41ada100b629c3033aa7>:0)
UnityEditor.PostprocessBuildPlayer.Postprocess (UnityEditor.BuildTargetGroup targetGroup, UnityEditor.BuildTarget target, System.String installPath, System.String companyName, System.String productName, System.Int32 width, System.Int32 height, UnityEditor.BuildOptions options, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry usedClassRegistry, UnityEditor.Build.Reporting.BuildReport report) (at <3b1af5075b0340cfb428dfcef292b2ea>:0)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr, Boolean&)
```

3:

```
Build completed with a result of 'Failed'
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr, Boolean&)
```

Comment: Please add the code snippet that you are trying to run. Or atleast an overview of the code.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback on my first post, although I'm not sure what code I should show. I have no clue where the origin of the error lays, my only guess is that it originates from the CloudOnce plugin which I imported as a package under the asset menu. The error is simply a build error, and I can unfortunately don't trace it down to any one script.

Comment: Tell us what you did, & what you've tried to make.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just had the exact same issue (and found your post). After some research, I've found the following answers: https://answers.unity.com/questions/1745738/android-sdk-not-found-or-invalid-in-unity.html and https://answers.unity.com/questions/1684441/android-sdk-not-found-error-in-unity-201930f1.html

Please follow the instructions:

1. Download Android Studio (with SDK Manager) https://developer.android.com/studio
2. Run SDK manager
3. Download SDK to specific folder
4. Uncheck "Android SDK Tools installed with Unity" in external tools dialog box and specify (in external tools dialog box) the specific folder where SDK is installed
5. In CloudOnce settings: "Run Setup" and Save configuration
6. Ensure your Target SDK is installed (https://forum.unity.com/threads/still-target-android-sdk-of-24-not-installed-after-it-had-been-installed-by-android-studio-setting.534821/)

Then you should be able Build your project. Let us know if it works for you too!

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, but it works now so THANK YOU SO MUCH! Afterward, I got I ton of new errors which apparently was fixable by creating a new keystore file. Unfortunately, it won't show the leaderboard when clicking on it, but I guess that's a problem for a different thread. Again, thank you so much!

Answer (score 3):

I just run into this issue and I solved it in the following steps:

Note: I am using the CloudOnce package.

1. Make sure you installed `CloudOnce` package correctly
2. In `Unity > Window > CloudOnce > Editor`
3. Make sure you have the google play id added and click set up
4. `Save`
5. It will generate a `AndroidManifest.xml` file:

[image]